# .NET WebAPI Cache Data on Start

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple .Net WebAPI that I need to instantiate a class on start (just once).  This instance needs to be available to each controller.

How/Where do I load this data on application start (where do I make my instance) and how do I access this instance from each controller?  Do I need DI?

Edit: Running Framework, not Core.

Comment: You don't need DI, but if you are using [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I think you should.

Comment: @Crowcoder, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Make a singleton class and Initalize it in startup.cs

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

// Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
// not to mark type as beforefieldinit
static Singleton()
{
}

private Singleton()
{
}

public static Singleton Instance
{
get
{
return instance;
}
}
}
```